# load resource: the server responded with a status of 413 (Request Entity Too Large)

Tags: php, upload, image-uploading, http-status-code-413

I have a serious problem. When i upload an image file from form via php post method after 15 seconds i have the following response **load resource: the server responded with a status of 413 (Request Entity Too Large)**

The fact here is that my image size is just 915 Kilobytes and the limit into my apache server php.ini file is set to **post_max_size = 20M** and **upload_max_filesize = 20M** , that means that my image file of 915 kb's should normally succeed to upload but unfortunatelly doesn't.

Does someone knows how can i solve this problem, i tried to increase the above values **post_max_size** and **upload_max_filesize** but i have the same response!

Also the process of post happen via ajax post method

Comment: Make sure you are editting the correct php.ini, Sometimes you have multiples php.ini in your server. Check the correct location in your phpinfo();

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Yes is the correct php.ini file, but anyway the default value is always set to post_max_size = 20M and upload_max_filesize = 20M. Maybe There is a problem with execution time

Comment: Are you certain it's PHP and not the HTTP Server causing the problem?

Comment: @Sean i am not sure about that, how can i check this, the process happened via ajax post method

Comment: It's usually going to be nginx or apache.  Are you running on a cloud service or using a local machine?

Comment: @Sean I am running on a local machine using apache

Comment: Apache a 2GB file limit by default, so that should be fine.  Have you tried placing <?php phpinfo(); ?> in your file to make sure that PHP is picking on your changes?

Comment: @Sean No i don't have phpinfo(); in my file. I will place it at the top of my file i guess and i'll come back with the feedback

Comment: @Sean I placed phpinfo(); but i have still the same response :(